# Strange error in parent descendant jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have read the [tutorial about jquery selectors](http://w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp).

it is mentioned that:

`parent descendant - $("div p") - All <p> elements that are descendants of a <div> element`

they provided a [demo](http://w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_parent_descendant) which works fine:

but i still can't able to figure out why this won't worked:

```
<p class="ee">
    <h4><span> The backgroud color don't changed</span></h4>
</p>
<script>
    $(".ee span").css("background-color","yellow");
</script>
```

[jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LnJQY/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your markup is wrong

```
<p class="ee">
     <h4><span> The backgroud color don't changed</span></h4>
</p>
```

you can not have `<h4>` tag indside `p` tag

so `browser render` this as

```
<p class="ee"></p>
     <h4><span> The backgroud color don't changed</span></h4>
<p></p>
```

So your below selector doesn't work. as there is no `span` inside class `ee`

```
$(".ee span").css("background-color","yellow");
```

---

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1